# FB Open Graph Check Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm implementing a simple Facebook "Like" button on a voting site but want an option which votes using the internal "Like" system for anyone who doesn't have a Facebook account/doesn't want to log in (this may seem like an odd request but this is a requirement for the client).

So basically I'd like a way of detecting if someone is logged in without having to use the graph API - just using Open Graph Protocol. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe) to `auth.statusChange` event, it might do the trick, as noted on [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus):

> Typically you will want to use the auth.sessionChange event. But in rare cases, you want to distinguish between these three states:
>
> - Connected
> - Logged into Facebook but not connected with your application
> - Not logged into Facebook at all.
>
> The FB.Event.subscribe and FB.Event.unsubscribe functions are used to subscribe to these events.

Returned `status` would contain either `connected`, `notConnected` (logged in to facebook but not to your app) or `unknown`.

I am not sure if this would work as planned though as I haven't tried it myself. It might return `notConnected` status only for users that authorized your app in the past, but it seems like a step in the right direction.